# Problems with the popups while using leaflet on Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, leaflet

I have two issues with my map while using Chrome that I don't have with Firefox nor Edge.

The first one is the position of the tip of the popups. Firefox and Edge show them on the center of the popup while Chrome does it on the left.
[Tip on Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6rP1O.png)
Also I have a popup showing an image, it works fine on Firefox and Edge but on Chrome

```
.Legend {width:384px;
height:318px;

var LegendPopup = L.popup({
offset:[455,275],minWidth:384,minHeight:318}).setContent('<img class="Legend" src="leaflet/images/LegendBig.png" alt="Legend" >'
);
```

I tried to force a minimum size of the popup but Chrome still showing it like this.[Image of the popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhEel.png)

The Chrome version I use is 57.0.2987.98 (64-bit)

Comment: is it a problem you have on this page ? http://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/example.html

Comment: No, this one works alright with Chrome

Comment: Cannot reproduce on Chromium 57.0.2987.0 http://playground-leaflet.rhcloud.com/muve/1/edit?html,output If that page does not reproduce your issue on your setup, please provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Now it's working. Next time I'll restart my laptop 1st thing...
Thanks for the answers.